# How do I sort items into objects via timestamps

Tags: arrays, typescript, sorting, timestamp

I have two arrays of objects, which I want to combine into one array in order of the timestamps that are a part of each object. The first array is an exact second, and the second array is a range of an hour. I want to input the 'humidity' values in the array with the exact timestamps into the one with the hourly ranges, according to where they fit in, time wise. How do I do this in typescript? Both arrays/objects are sorted by time.

For example:

```
[{id: 1, timestampUtc: "2019-02-22T08:24:00Z", humidity: 74},
 {id: 2, timestampUtc: "2019-02-24T06:20:00Z", humidity: 39},
 {id: 3, timestampUtc: "2019-02-26T020:03:00Z", humidity: 35}]
```

and

```
[{id: 4, starttimestampUtc: "2019-02-22T08:00:00Z", endtimestampUtc: "2019-02-22T09:00:00Z", precipitation: .03},
 {id: 5, starttimestampUtc: "2019-02-24T06:00:00Z", endtimestampUtc: "2019-02-24T07:00:00Z", precipitation: .3},
 {id: 6, starttimestampUtc: "2019-02-26T020:00:00Z",endtimestampUtc: "2019-02-26T021:00:00Z", precipitation: .12}]
```

to look like:

```
[{id: 4, starttimestampUtc: "2019-02-22T08:00:00Z", endtimestampUtc: "2019-02-22T09:00:00Z", precipitation: .03, humidity: 74},
 {id: 5, starttimestampUtc: "2019-02-24T06:00:00Z", endtimestampUtc: "2019-02-24T07:00:00Z", precipitation: .3, humidity: 39},
 {id: 6, starttimestampUtc: "2019-02-26T020:00:00Z", endtimestampUtc: "2019-02-26T021:00:00Z", precipitation: .12, , humidity: 35}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by converting the UTC timestamps into date objects. The following code seemed to work for me, where a and b are your two arrays. I also noticed that there is an extra 0 in the timestamps of the final element of each array.

```
b.map((element) => {
let entry = a.find((e) => {
    let d = new Date(e.timestampUtc)
    let start = new Date(element.starttimestampUtc)
    let end = new Date(element.endtimestampUtc)
    return (d >= start && d <= end)
})
if(entry !== undefined) {
    element.humidity = entry.humidity
}
return element

})
```